# Add httpOnly flag to ss-id/ss-pid servicestack cookies

Tags: rest, servicestack, httponly, cookie-httponly

I'm working on a self-hosted windows HTTP service using service stack, I have a request to implement basic authentication (username/password) to authenticate the calling applications. This is the code I'm using right now and it's working fine:

```
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession() {},
 new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() })); //CustomBasicAuthProvider()

        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

        var userRepository = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepository);
        string hash;
        string salt;

        new SaltedHash().GetHashAndSaltString("passwordinhere", out hash, out salt);
                userRepository.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    DisplayName = "userdisplayname",
                    UserName = "usernameinhere",
                    PasswordHash = hash,
                    Salt = salt
                }
                    , "app");
```

When I inspect the response header coming from my service I see clearly that it contains 2 cookies:

Set-Cookie: ss-id=dT8Yy6ejhgfjhgfkVvcxcxCNtngYRS4;path=/

Set-Cookie: ss-pid=p4lsgo18JhYF4CTcxkhgkhgffRZob;path=/;expires=Fri, 09 Jan 2037 12:17:03 GMT

I need to configure ServiceStack to add ;httpOnly flag to those cookies for security purpose but I can't find how to do it.

So guys, anyone has an idea how to do that? any idea is very welcome.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control whether `HttpOnly` flag are set on Cookies with `Config.AllowNonHttpOnlyCookies` which by default is `false` so would always set the `HttpOnly` flag. Unfortunately this setting was ignored with self-hosts which is now resolved with [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/979faff6fc90fadf4f8ebcb6e8c2fdc2b9cb87f7) which will now populate `HttpOnly` flag for all Cookies by default.

This change is available from v4.5.5+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks for the reply